# Blank Screen and only pop up "Not Responding" dialog.

Tags: android, epub

I am unable to figure out why I am stuck at this point although there is no error is my coding. My problem is actually, it doesn't print out my epub, as well as it just hangs there, till the not responding dialog comes up.

My code is as below:

```
            package com.epub;

    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.util.List;

    import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;
    import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Resource;
    import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Spine;
    import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.SpineReference;
    import nl.siegmann.epublib.epub.EpubReader;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.res.AssetManager;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class EpubReaderActivity extends Activity {
        WebView webView;
        Book book;
        TextView tv;
        String line;
        String linez;
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            tv = new TextView(this);
            webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            AssetManager am = getAssets();
            try {
                InputStream epubInputStream = am.open("testbook.epub");
                book = (new EpubReader()).readEpub(epubInputStream);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("epublib", e.getMessage());
            }
            Spine spine = book.getSpine(); 
            List<SpineReference> spineList = spine.getSpineReferences() ;
            int count = spineList.size();
            tv.setText(Integer.toString(count));
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
                Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

                try {
                    InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                    try {

                        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                            linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                    //do something with stream
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
            webView.loadData(linez, "text/html", "utf-8");

        }
    }
```

Mind helping me out on this point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pu this code inside a thread as this takes time to write the data and load a web view 
Thread is a different part of execution and you will have to wait for few sconds if yor file is large 
you can also put a progress dialog to show loading of webview

```
           new Thread(){
        public void run() {
                    for (int i = 0; count > i; i++) {
                    Resource res = spine.getResource(i);

            try {
                InputStream is = res.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                try {

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        linez =   string.append(line + "\n").toString();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

                //do something with stream
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

     };
    }.start();
```

Comment: Now I used your code, a null text came up instead of the epub,

Comment: my logcat is flooded with GC_FOR_MALLOC

Answer (score 4):

An [ANR](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/responsiveness.html)(Application Not Responding) happens generally when you do a heavy job. In Android, if the OS can't execute one code line within about 5 seconds, the ANR dialog wil pop up. From your codes, it seems that you are reading and parsing an .epub file from your asset folder. I am not familiar with epub files, but I suspect this is a heavy task which blocks your app.

How about start a Thread or [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to read the file so the main thread would not be blocked?

Comment: +1 exact info. More info, perform background task inside AsyncTask.

Answer (score -1):

More your file reading code form `onCreaate()` to `onResume().` As data will be read once the UI show to user